# Can the said two sequences be coprime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is the following statement true?

$$\exists a,b \in \mathbb{N}\text{ }\text{ }\text{such that } \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ we have } \text{gcd}(2^{m}-a, 2^{n}-b) = 1 $$

$\textbf{Some possible ideas:}$

For every odd prime $p$ and positive integers $m,n$ we have $2^{(p-1)m}-a \equiv 1-a \mod p$
and $2^{(p-1)n}-b \equiv 1-b \mod p$. Thus clearly we must consider the cases for $a,b$ where $\text{gcd}(1-a,1-b)$ is a power of two.

Note here that $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,...\}$ (there is no $0$).

Comment: $a=0$ and $b=1$ should work, right? (depending on your definition of $\mathbb N$)

Comment: Right, I should add that $\mathbb{N}$ starts with $1$.

Comment: You need at least a partial reformulation, as if $a = 2^z$, then at $m =z, 2^m - a = 0$ and $0$ is only coprime to $1$ (in $\mathbb{Z}^+$). I'm guessing that in general, you'll want $2^m - a, 2^n - b \in \mathbb{Z}^+ $. So your question might be better as: $$?[\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+](\forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \mid 2^m-a, 2^n-b \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \land \gcd(2^m-a, 2^n-b)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is the same as asking "Do there exist odd integers $a$ and $b$ such that the set of primes dividing any of the integers $2^m-a$ is disjoint from the set of primes dividing any of the integers $2^n-b$?". The answer is almost certainly going to be no.

Indeed, it would follow from Artin's primitive root conjecture that $2$ is a primitive root modulo infinitely many primes; for such a prime $p$ that doesn't divide $ab$, there will be a solution to $2^m\equiv a\pmod p$ and also a solution to $2^n\equiv b\pmod p$, and hence $\gcd(2^m-a,2^n-b) \ge p$. (Indeed this argument shows that these gcds must be unbounded.)

Comment: Wait... Artin's primitive root conjecture is not proven... (I will accept this answer if it actually is, only upvoted for now)

Comment: True, this isn't a proof. But we only need something much weaker: for every $a$ and $b$, there exists a prime not dividing $ab$ for which both $a$ and $b$ are in the subgroup generated by $2$. Perhaps that much has been proved somewhere.